# Body background with 3 background colors

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

Is it possible to have the body color as 3 different colors - I am creating a website (just for fun) based on the Scottish clubs and I was hoping to change the background color to represent the colors of the clubs ie - Rangers Red>White>Blue and Celtic Green>White>Gold

Here is an example of the 3 color - [image]

Comment: Why not? An absolutely positioned div with 100% height & width, filled with three divs having 100% widths and 33.34% heights.

Comment: some of the clubs have 2 colors so doing it with 3 divs would mess up the layout

Comment: The obvious answer is yes. Are you referring to the case of not using extra elements, with just CSS on `body`?

Comment: yes - only using css not adding more or removing divs

Comment: And what do you mean by 3 different colors? Vertical stripes? Repeating? Or just 3 "equal blocks"? Vertical/horizontal?

Comment: "some of the clubs have 2 colors so doing it with 3 divs would mess up the layout" - okay, make it two for some clubs? There's ***no*** universal CSS for any clubs, considering that any of them also have different colors.

Comment: 2 or 3 equal colors (i will have the info in divs with a light color background like cream)

Comment: ive put an exmple of a 3 color background (not exact color but for layout example)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Linear Gradient Approach

You can make use of `linear-gradient` background images like in the below snippet. Making the color stop point of one color as the starting point of the next color would produce a block like effect instead of an actual gradient like effect.

Linear gradients are supported in the [recent  versions of all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients). If you want to support IE9 and lower then you may have to look at some libraries (like CSS3 PIE) or use a different approach like `box-shadow` (inset) or some extra (or pseudo) elements.

**Horizontal Stripes:**

To create horizontal stripes, an angle (or sides) need not be specified because the default angle is 0 degree (or `to bottom` like mentioned in **jedrzejchalubek**'s answer).

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, blue 66.66%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
```

**Vertical Stripes:**

To create vertical stripes, you need to either mention the angle (90deg) as the first parameter for the gradient (or specify `to right` meaning the gradient goes from left of the screen to the right).

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, red 33.33%, white 33.33%, white 66.66%, blue 66.66%);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!-- to avoid browser prefixes -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Box Shadow Approach with Viewport Units

You can make use of inset `box-shadow` along with viewport units also to produce the striped effect with just a single element. This would be supported by even IE9 because both [`box-shadow`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) and [viewport units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) are supported.

**Horizontal Stripes:**

To create horizontal stripes, the Y-axis offset of the box-shadows should be assigned in equal splits. Here we use 33.33vh, 66.66vh and 99.99vh because there is only a 3 color split.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 33.33vh 0px red, inset 0px 66.66vh 0px white, inset 0px 99.99vh 0px blue;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

**Vertical Stripes:**

This is very similar to the approach for creating horizontal stripes except for the fact that here we change the X-axis offset of the `box-shadow`.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  box-shadow: inset 33.33vw 0px 0px red, inset 66.66vw 0px 0px white, inset 99.99vw 0px 0px  blue;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

---

### Pseudo Element Approach

This approach has the highest browser support because it doesn't use viewport units and [pseudo-elements with a single-colon syntax](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore) are supported even by IE8. However, the drawback of this approach is that if you need a split of 4 or more colors then extra elements would be needed.

**Horizontal Stripes:**

To create horizontal stripes, the pseudo elements get 33.33% height of the `body` whereas the width is 100%. One pseudo element is positioned on the top and the other is positioned at the bottom.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body:before,
body:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33.33%;
}
body:before {
  top: 0px;
  background: blue;
}
body:after {
  bottom: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

**Vertical Stripes:**

To create vertical stripes, the pseudo elements get 33.33% width of the `body` whereas the height is 100%. One pseudo element is positioned on the left and the other is positioned at the right.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
body:before,
body:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33.33%;
}
body:before {
  left: 0px;
  background: blue;
}
body:after {
  right: 0px;
  background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Use generator http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor with color-stops very close to each other.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #3056ff 0%,#3056ff 32%,#ff3033 33%,#ff282c 66%,#2989d8 67%,#2989d8 67%,#7db9e8 100%);
```

Comment: +1 I think we have actually posted very similar answers at the same time (no accusations whatsoever, just a statement). Coming to the gradient itself you can make the stop point of one color as the start point of the next (instead of as 32% stop and 33% start) to avoid even the small gradient like change over of colors :)

Comment: I assume you mean color-stops and not *keyframes*