# How can I generate a solid gradient style in CSS?

Tags: html, css

```css
div {
  height: 2em;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, green 25%, black 50%, blue 25%);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This is how I generate my bar with 3 colors

[image]

It looks like the image, but I don't want the gradient effect between green and black, but I just want to display those three colors with that proportion solidly, just like the black box that I sketched below.

Any help?

Comment: The percentage values aren’t _how many_ percent to fill, they assign positions _from and to_ on a linear scale. So when you assign one color at position 25% and another at position 50%, the gap will gradiently shift from one to the other. To make the transition appear to be solid, make one start at 0% and end at 25%, and then make the next color start at 26% and go to 75%, before the last color starts at 76% and ends at 100% :o)

Comment: https://cssgradient.io/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Body background with 3 background colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359310/body-background-with-3-background-colors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the the gradient you are looking for ?

[image: Gradient test]

```
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0,255,0,1) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 25%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%);
```

Starting next color value at the same point than the previous one will cause the gradient effect to disappear.

https://codepen.io/GuillaumeGautier/pen/jOWWKLG