# Plotly: Is there a way to create block "annotations" in the plot for dropdown box?

Tags: plotly

So I am referring to this documentation: https://plotly.com/python/dropdowns/

Is there a way to highlight clusters using annotation? In addition to the code of the example in the documentation, I added some block of colors (using fig.add_shape()) for each cluster in the background as below:

[image]

If I use the same code as in the example, the layout will be updated and blocks of color will be deleted. I want to keep the colored blocks, and be able to highlight the clusters in the example.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that the intent of your question was to select annotations in a drop down and furthermore to add annotations in a specific area to all selections. In that case, the annotation content is to be added to the dropdown content. Since the data for the shape you want to add is unknown, I have added a rectangle shape with the appropriate data to the code in the reference.

```
# Add buttons that add shapes
cluster0 = [dict(type="circle",
                 xref="x", yref="y",
                 x0=min(x0), y0=min(y0),
                 x1=max(x0), y1=max(y0),
                 line=dict(color="DarkOrange")),
            dict(type='shape',
                 xref='x', yref='y',
                 x0=1.0, x1=4.0,
                 y0=3.0, y1=5.0,
                 line=dict(color='RoyalBlue'))
           ]
cluster1 = [dict(type="circle",
                 xref="x", yref="y",
                 x0=min(x1), y0=min(y1),
                 x1=max(x1), y1=max(y1),
                 line=dict(color="Crimson")),
            dict(type='shape',
                 xref='x', yref='y',
                 x0=1.0, x1=4.0,
                 y0=3.0, y1=5.0,
                 line=dict(color='RoyalBlue'))
           ]
cluster2 = [dict(type="circle",
                 xref="x", yref="y",
                 x0=min(x2), y0=min(y2),
                 x1=max(x2), y1=max(y2),
                 line=dict(color="RebeccaPurple")),
            dict(type='shape',
                 xref='x', yref='y',
                 x0=1.0, x1=4.0,
                 y0=3.0, y1=5.0,
                 line=dict(color='RoyalBlue'))            
           ]
```

[image]

Comment: To clarify my intention, for a specific reason, I added "background" colors behind the clusters (color blocks) to kinda to separate them (for ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31359310/body-background-with-3-background-colors). I kinda got the answer from your answer by adding the coordinates of 3 color blocks in each cluster list... to make those background colors stay and the cluster annotation will change according to my selection from dropdown box... I am just not sure if that is the most optimal way to do it.